# Django select related performance

Tags: python, django, performance

So I am debating whether or not to use [Django's select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or not for performance issues.

In the documentation, it says that this is a "performance booster" because it does not need to query the database anymore, but that would clearly mean it has to store a lot more data locally, which can be exhaustive if you need to do a lot of separate calls for a lot of different users.

**What are the pros and cons of performance with Django's `select_related`? And when should (or shouldn't) it be used?**

Comment: It will get as memory-extensive as the peak consumption multiplied by number of workers. Python doesn't free memory to OS, but it also doesn't take more of it has some space left in the pool. Also, you are not displaying say, milions of entries on a single view, are you?

Comment: @kroolik Not in a view, this is for querying specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont use select_related or not you will eat memory each time you access a related object, so if you have to access related objects it won't make that much of a difference wrt/ memory usage and can indeed save *a lot* of db access cost - specially if your db server is not on the same node as your django instance(s). To make a long story short:

- as a general guideline: use select_related (with appropriate params to limit what relationships should be followed) when you know you'll need the related object.
- if in doubt, don't try to guess, test and profile (yes it requires quite some infrastructure to do proper testing and profiling here but hey, that's how it is).

My own experience: careful use of select_related can vastly improve execution time, never had a problem with memory but we usually do our best to avoid loading millions of rows when we just need a couple ones (doing proper filtering, slicing etc *before* the query is actually eval'd).

Comment: +1 this is essentially what I'm looking for, but it is a bit vague (although so is my question). My issue about using it is that sometimes (and it wont be known due to chaining) there will be many calls and sometimes there will be just one. So I am just not sure if `select_related` will be beneficial or not.

Comment: @RyanSaxe : well there's no one-size-fits-all answer here, and there's a balance between maintainability and optimization. But: you can add the select_related all as long as you have not eval'd the queryset so it's up to you to check in your code (templates included) when it makes sense to use it or not. You can also use the debug toolbar app to check for places (views/templates...) where it might be appropriate.